# Attribute to chance cell to combobox

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, attributes

I use dataGridView.DataSource = myList; to populate a dataGridView.

I use the following code to hide a class member:

```
 [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
 public string SomeInformation { get; set; }
```

But, is there also a way to say that a class member should be represented as a ComboBox?

If not, is there any way that I can change it with code? I tried the following:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
comboBoxCell.DataSource = State.Instance.ProductCategories.ToList();
dataGridView[2, 0] = comboBoxCell;
dataGridView[2, 0].Value = State.Instance.ProductCategories.ToList()[0];
```

The value of the field will be fine, but there is still no ComboBox.

Any help?

**Edit:**

I now use the following code:

```
 dataGridView.DataSource = State.Instance.Products;
 dataGridView.DataError += delegate(object o, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs args)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(args.Exception.Message);
 };

 DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
 col.DataPropertyName = "Categorie";
 col.Name = "Categorie";
 col.Visible = true;
 col.HeaderText = "Categorie";
 col.DataSource = State.Instance.ProductCategories.ToList();
 col.DisplayMember = "Name";
 col.DisplayIndex = 1;

 dataGridView.Columns.Add(col);

 dataGridView.CellEndEdit += delegate(object o, DataGridViewCellEventArgs args)
 {
     State.Instance.Save();
     // If I check the value here, it is a string.
 };
```

But when I save the state, the value is not being changed. Can that be because I added the column myself and it does not know where to save it?

```
    [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
    public ProductCategory Categorie { get; set; }
```

And in the CellEndEdit event, I only get the string back, but not the whole object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set *DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns=false* and then add all columns in code, or auto generate columns and then add your custom column (change DisplayIndex to set its position):

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
col.DataPropertyName = "SomeInformation";
col.Name = "colSomeInformation";
col.Visible = true;
col.HeaderText = "Some Information"
col.DataSource = State.Instance.ProductCategories.ToList();
// set other column properties here...

dataGridView.Columns.Add(col);
```

I once had to autogenerate datagridview's columns of different types based on external settings, and I used xml config files for this. As far as I know, there's no built-in solution to do it.

**EDIT:**

How the ValueMember works:

```
class ProductCategory
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}

class Product
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int CategoryID {get;set;}
}


// Example data binding:

BindingList<Products> bl = new BindingList<Products>(State.Instance.Products.ToList());
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource=bl;

dataGridView.DataSource = bs;

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
col.DataSource = State.Instance.Categories.ToList();
col.DataPropertyName = "CategoryID";
col.DisplayMember= "Name"; // name of category
col.ValueMember ="ID"; // id of category
```

Comment: Even though I preferred a different solution, this fixed it. I get an ArgumentException when I select something in the ComboBox. The value is invalid. Not sure why though.

Comment: @ErwinOkken DataGridViewComboBoxColumn have DisplayMember and ValueMember, set them and make sure the type of ValueMember in the source is string (same as your SomeInformation property). Also there may be some strange behaviour when there are nulls in data sources

Comment: After adding a DisplayMember, the value was gone. But, the value that I get back now is a string. The type of "SomeInformation" is a custom class. I should have mentioned that..

Comment: @ErwinOkken default ValueMember is the whole item from DataSource collection. If you set it by name, then there is only value of a single property in it. If your DataGridView is bound to a datasource, the value in property "selected" in DataPropertyName has to correspond to that "selected" in ValueMember of the column

Comment: Even if I leave my ValueMember empty (and remove ToString()), I still get a string back. I don't exactly get your last sentence.

Comment: @ErwinOkken sorry that my comment was not clear, english is not my native language. I added an edit.

Comment: Great example! But that means that I have to have double data? A real reference (custom class) and a unique number for the product category?

Comment: @ErwinOkken you just have to have the way to link your data: add some sort of unique ID to your class then select the ProductCategory using Linq when you need it (I usually do it this way), or in Product class have a property: public ProductCategory Category{get;set;}, then don't set ValueMember and set DataPropertyName="Category"

Comment: I updated my post, I thought it was working but it is still not working. Any clue why?

Comment: there seems to be some sort of bug, and when ValueMember is not set, it returns ToString() or DisplayMember. Here is some solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515745/datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-not-taking-valuemember

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that that is not possible.